# Can't install ubuntu 14.04 with usb & md5 check sums are different

Tags: usb, system-installation, live-usb, md5sum

when I try to install Ubuntu with usb stick 
Just gets to where its about to start with the purple ubuntu loading screen then it goes back to text and gives this message

```
BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash) 
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) mount: mounting /dev/loop0 on //filesystem.squashfs failed: Invalid argument   
Can not mount /dev/loop0 (/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs) on //filesystem.squashfs
```

When checked, it comes out that **Md5 check sums are different**.

Please tell me what to do to solve this????

In detail..
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you have calculated `md5sum` for your downloaded ubuntu.iso file and it differs to the original one, then you are not recommended to do anything with this .iso fle, but throw it away.

Download again and be sure that `md5sum` matches. Only after this make your USB device bootable with this image.

Answer (score 0):

Also as the **md5 check sums are different**, it means that you have downloaded a modified Ubuntu iso file, which can be(most likely will be) harmful. So **DO NOT USE IT**.

As for the error, it is most likely a result of **wrong command line arguments**. Check that the mountpoint really exist.